# Free program to generate ER diagram for exisiting SQLite Database

Tags: gratis, er-diagram, sqlite

I have a SQLite database that I have created.  In order to document it, I hope to create an ER diagram.  Is there a free tool out there that will import the database and spit out an er diagram?  Any platform is fine, though Windows I guess is the slight preference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One tool is Schema Crawler (along with a graphics add-on) which is open source.  It is java based, so should run on windows (or almost any other OS).

- [Schema Crawler Official Page](https://www.schemacrawler.com/index.html)
- [Schema Crawler Github Page](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler)

Comment: It works pretty well out of the box.  I just need to do a few minor tweaks and I have it.  Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Really? It seems to have a bunch of 3rd party dependiences - downloadable, but not bundled. I'm getting "Graphviz was not available to create the requested graph (...)" when attempting on a clean install

Comment: It seems slightly cumbersome to use. Rather than just invoking something like `creatediagram mydbfile.sqlite` after adding the installation directory to the path, it seems one has to run some script for starting a db server and then run the application with a long chain of parameters, which will then somehow access the runinng server.

Comment: A solution which involves opening your Sqlite Db in a tool, exporting it & then importing into MySql Workbench, is slightly less trouble. It's what I am doing - until I can find a simpler, free, solution. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972916/how-to-create-eer-model-from-a-sqlite-db

Comment: On Linux, with package *graphviz* installed, for *sqlite* databases, the command to generate a schema diagram is `./schemacrawler.sh -server sqlite -database $db  -password=""  -infolevel=standard -command=schema -outputformat=png -outputfile=mydb--diagram.png` where $db is just a string with the absolute path to the .sqlite file.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently discovered this tool which has an ER Diagram capability based on SQLite datatbase (in actual fact, I use geopackages - a GIS implementation of sqlite databases.

**DBeaver**

The only issue I had was the software itself needed the sqlite.jdbc drivers installed and configured manually - It didn't pick them up automatically
You just need to configure the application to look for the sqlite.jdbc drivers (download them first obviously, set in classpath, then configure DBeaver to look for that folder for drivers).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy homemade tool: [sqlite3todot](https://github.com/chunky/sqlite3todot). Very tiny that only includes a 191-line C file, and renders with dot/graphviz.