# Creating an ER model automaticly from existing Postgres DB

Tags: windows, data-visualization

I am looking for a program, which allows me to automate the modeling of my existing database.

I am using a Postgres database with many different schemas and I want to share the model of the DB with a colleague. In order to do so, I could use online tools like [draw.io](http://draw.io), but this is time-consuming. This is why I am searching for a tool to automate this process.

**Requirements:**

- Should work on windows 10
- Should work with Postgres databases
- Automated creation of the ER model
- Should be open source/free

I am aware of the  question [Free program to generate ER diagram for exisiting SQLite Database](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2708/33702) but I can't get this program to run.

Comment: Not open source or free, but [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/) by JetBrains automatically draws ERD-style diagrams from a given database.

Comment: @BasilBourque I've tested the suggested software and it did its job very well ( they have a 30-day free trial) however, I still would love to see a free solution for my problem :)